# Kubernetes kube-proxy iptables rules seem to be redundant

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

### Context

Maybe there is unnecessary redundancy in the `iptables` rules generated by `kubeadm init` for `kube-proxy`:

```
iptables -t filter -S
```

output:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-N KUBE-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-N KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The `10.244.0.0/16` range corresponds to the pod overlay network.

Lets focus on the `FORWARD` chain.

```
-P FORWARD DROP
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

### Question:

Why the `KUBE-FORWARD` accepts packages within the overlay network, when their connection state is `RELATED` or `ESTABLISHED` if `FORWARD` chain will accept all packet traffic within the overlay network regardless their connection state?

### Note:

The kubernetes cluster works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This duplication is there, because the default FORWARD policy can be disabled for some reason, and Kubernetes still wants to forward packets that either:

1. Are marked with "masqueradeMark" (those can start new connections)
2. Are part of already established connection

You can try reading the comments in the k8s source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/proxy/iptables/proxier.go#L1325

In general, one should expect some duplication in iptables rules when those rules are automatically managed. It makes it easier to code the automation.